# Oscilloscope as monochrome bitmap image viewer

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, oscilloscope

Iam a beginner in arduino and other open source platform programming and  I came across a DIY project which involves using oscilloscope as an image viewer,but this project involves ATmega16 AVR IC1 microcontoller (the schematic is given in the image following)  .Can this project be done using arduino,if possible can anybody give me the sketch for the program.Thank you.[image]

Comment: Poor choice of resistor ratios: 68k / 33k would give a more accurate response. 3% vs 12% error. Also probably the lowest 3 bits will have disappointing performance due to error/tolerances.

Comment: Questions seeks code to be written are not on topic here.  If you have the original ATmega16, porting it to an ATmega328p should be a simple exercise.  While less recommended, you may be able to put it inside an Arduino "sketch" program structure, but would probably want to disable the usual timer interrupt used there to avoid it causing pauses in your updates.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific on the program to be written.I was very desperate to make this project and didn't have ATmega AVR microcontroller so i wished to do this project in arduino instead of using AVR, that's why I asked this question.Being a beginner I don't know the scope(i mean the libraries to be used and so on) available in the arduino platform to do this project.On the whole I want a replacement for the ATmega16 IC1@Chris Stratton

Answer (score 3):

You will learn a WHOLE LOT by reading about how oscilloscopes work and coming up with a sketch on your own.

You might want to find a pre-assembled DAC (digital to analog converter) shield that comes with an Arduino library to make things easier as a beginner.

The schematic you show is called an R2R DAC, or resistor ladder DAC. It would work just fine in the Arduino, but two channels of that requires a decent number of pins.

Note that to do 2D images you will need another DAC to generate the other axis. If you only want to do raster images, you could design an analog ramp generator with op amps, but I suspect that may be beyond your level at this point, and code might get you there faster and keep you more focused on learning a single thing for now.

Comment: I think what your saying is, I reached a project beyond my scope at this level. so I think I will study about the oscilloscope and try to do this project on my own.Thank you for your guidance

Comment: @ArAvind It's generally considered bad manners to come in here and ask people to design something for you. But you can certainly ask specific questions of the form: "I know this thing, and that thing, and I have tried this thing, but I don't understand this part."

Comment: Sorry for asking such a question and I will make sure it will not happen again.And thank you for guiding me in the right direction.@Daniel